# LinearLayout: Aligning to the Right of the parent

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, android-linearlayout

Pleae have a look at the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/open_file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/open" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to align the `Button` to the right corner of the layout. How can I do this?

Comment: I can't see any code.  I can see some XML data.  To put the button in the bottom right, the easiest way would be to use a `Relativelayout` with layout_alignParentBottom and layout_alignParentRight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` for this `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Try below data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/open_file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/open" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't solve the question, can you do the same with LinearLayout?

Comment: It does work for me, can you tell me what is the exact issue

Comment: You can try below answer for LinearLayout implementation

Comment: I was trying to say that the question ask for align the element to the right of the parent in a LinearLayout, you can't just change off the layout. Your solution works and well but you need to change the layout that's all. I was wondering if you can do the same without touch the linearlayout.

Answer (score 9):

Another possible way of doing this is by using the layout_weight attribute. This has my preference, because it fills up all available space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/open_file_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"
        android:gravity="start|left"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end|right"
        android:text="open" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: AFAIK this wouldn't only place the button on the right, but stretch the width of the whole button.

Comment: More precisely, it will stretch both TextView and Button such that they fill up the space on a 3 to 1 ratio.

Comment: Right, I missed the weight for the TextView. Still, this means the width of your button changes if the width of the screen changes (think of landscape and tablet use). Questionable if that's a desired behavior.

Comment: what about Using Left Start| Right End, are not they must.?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi you're right, that's a must if you plan to deploy to Arabic regions, or just want to get rid of Android Studio warnings ;) I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/open_file_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"        
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/open" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filling View between the `TextView` and the `Button` using the `layout_weight` attribute:

```
<View android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_heigth="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Or better use a `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,it worked for me.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/open_file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/open" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```